# Site slides to left on mobile, expanded navigation menu too far right

Tags: wordpress

kyler4sps.com

When I go to the site on mobile it slides to the left revealing an empty margin and when I expand the header navigation menu it seems aligned too far to the right. I am using Namecheap Easy Wordpress and I went into the theme code editor to look for "owl-carousel" as another post suggested but I don't see owl anywhere and it doesn't look like any particular block is filling a width further right than the others

[Page Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96uAW.png)
[Menu Alignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzRUv.png)

I have tried going into the block editor and the code editor on both the WP admin dashboard and the theme's (intrance) built-in customier but there doesn't seem to be a setting for the expanded menu, just the header layout

Comment: simply add margins and paddings as you want to right side.

Comment: The editor doesn't seem to let me edit the expanded menu, it will let me edit the header width, and align the menu ceter, but not add margins to the menu. Do you think that will also fix the extra margin on the right or will it add to it?